# How to copy files alphabetically in order of date?

Tags: file, dos

I have a karaoke machine with a "feature" that it only displays songs in order of the file date timestamp. This is very annoying since I have over 500 songs and I often add new ones which always end up at the end of the list.

Is there a tool or DOS command that could solve this issue for me?

The machine only reads FAT32 USB memory sticks.

Comment: do you want a DOS command or a windows shell (`cmd.exe`) command? Still- Worth migrating to SuperUser I think.

Comment: I quote kos. Should be moved to su.com

Answer (score 0):

dir/o/p ?

Been years since I used DOS

Comment: I would be happy enough with a DOS copy command that would copy in alphabetic order.